# Java EE perspective in Eclipse version 2.1.1

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

Does **Eclipse 2.1.1** supports Java Enterprise Edition **(Java EE)** perspective? I didn't find this perspective when I downloaded eclipse 2.1.1 from eclipse archives website. I've to use this very old version of eclipse because I'm working on a legacy application and it uses some very old eclipse plugins that are only supported in older versions released before the year 2003. Any support regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. WTP's original code contribution to Eclipse took place in 2004. Prior to that, its contents lived in other commercial products and Open Source projects, and the perspective definition itself and a lot of the associated Java EE support was in an IBM commercial product.

Comment: Thanks a lot @nitind. Do you know any open source IDE of that time which support WTP. I know IBM's WebSphere studio developer(WSADIE) supports WTP at that time but it is a licenced software and not freeware.

Comment: Is there any other alternative to run those plugins in newer version of eclipse, if possible?

Comment: I do not know. It's not something I've ever looked into.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure because this is so old, but I would think it very unlikely.

Eclipse 2 had a different way of describing plugin dependencies which newer plugins don't use, so anything that is not built for Eclipse 2  won't work.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449 for your prompt reply.